# spaCy-like dependency graph navigation in CoreNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, stanford-parser

Is it possible to navigate the dependency parse tree in `CoreNLP` the way one does that in `spaCy` as described [here](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/dependency-parse#navigating)? So far I see that token attributes like lemmas, POS tags, etc. are retrievable through an index, e.g. `sent.lemmas(5)` returns the lemma of the sixth token. I am not sure this exists for dependency heads and relations. Is there an established way of using these apart from navigating the whole tree every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the regular API, I believe what you're looking for is the function:

```
Set<IndexedWord> SemanticGraph#vertexSet()
```

This iterates over all of the nodes in a dependency tree [/graph]. each `IndexedWord` is also a `CoreLabel`, which means it has all of the functions you know and love for tokens.

From the simple API -- which I gather is what you're using -- you can get a regular old dependency graph with:

```
SemanticGraph Sentence#dependencyGraph()
```

Comment: Does the `SemanticGraph#vertexSet()` return the `IndexedWord` objects in the order occurring in the sentence? I assume not because it's a `Set`. I was looking for something that makes it possible to access the data structure from the bottom up rather than through iteration over the tree.

Comment: Would vertexListSorted do the trick? Or the topologicalSort method? See http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.html for more.

Comment: Thanks, this works although it is not as convenient as I was hoping.